# Sensitive query search in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT VALUE FROM BILL WHERE VALUE='ABC123';
```

search results would bring back records with abc123, ABC123, aBc123, ABc123 also

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions:

First:

```
SELECT value 
FROM bill 
WHERE upper(VALUE) = 'ABC123';
```

Second:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = Linguistic;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = XGerman_CI; -- or any other language, e.g. XWEST_EUROPEAN_CI

SELECT value 
FROM bill 
WHERE VALUE = 'ABC123';
```

The `_CI` suffix of the nls_sort parameter tells Oracle to compare "case insensitive".

In both cases Oracle won't use an index unless you create a function based index.

For a complete list of possible NLS_SORT values, see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i637232

Comment: +1 for highlighting the indexing issue.  Performance can be badly hit if your query gets even a little bit complicated (I assume that the simplicity of the query means that it's an example only).

Answer (score 1):

use upper or lower function and give the exact value you need.

```
select value from bill where upper(value)='ABC123'
```

If you need all the value like abc,aBc,Abc,etc you can use below in `where` condition with your requirement

```
value in ('abc','aBc','Abc','ABC')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM BILL WHERE upper(VALUE)='ABC123';
```

But you'll loose the benefit of index on value, if exists.

However, you may create a function based index on upper(value).